# How do I duplicate records in my postgresql database?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two tables Structure and Bandit pages:

```
class Structure(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'structure'

    arm_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    page_url = db.Column(db.String())

class Bandit_pages(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'bandit_pages'
    campaign_id = db.Column(db.String())
    arm_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    status = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    __table_args__ = (
        PrimaryKeyConstraint('campaign_id', 'arm_id'),
        {},)
```

and here are the records which are getting saved

```
select * from structure ;
                  page_url                  | arm_id 
--------------------------------------------+--------
 XYZ.php                                    |      0
 mt3                                        |      1
(2 rows)

proj=# select * from bandit_pages ;
 campaign_id | arm_id | status 
-------------+--------+--------
 0           |      0 | t
 72297098    |      1 | f
(2 rows)
```

I wanted to store these values as

```
proj=# select * from bandit_pages ;
 campaign_id | arm_id | status 
-------------+--------+--------
 0           |      0 | t
 0           |      0 | f
 72297098    |      0 | t
 72297098    |      1 | f
(4 rows)
```

for which my code is:

```
def init(self):
    #code here
    self.bandit_pages = {}
        try:
            for arm_id in self.structure:
                new_bandit_page = Bandit_pages(campaign_id=str(arm_id), arm_id=arm_id, status=True)
                db.session.add(new_bandit_page)
            db.session.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            print("exception in BANDPAGEINIT insert", e)
            db.session.rollback()
```

I tried adding an extra line `new_bandit_page_1 = Bandit_pages(campaign_id=str(arm_id), arm_id=arm_id, status=True)` and added it using db.session.add(new_bandit_page_1) however it was not added? what could be the reason of not getting added? Is there any other way to add? Please help.

**EDIT**: I also tried by adding an extra line `new_bandit_page_1 = Bandit_pages(campaign_id=str(arm_id), arm_id=arm_id, status=True)` with db.session.add_all([new_bandit_page, new_bandit_page_1]) and that didn't help either.

Comment: It looks like both records have the same primary key `str(arm_id), arm_id`, so the session will bot add both.

Comment: @snakecharmerb thanks for the cue. I had made it a unique key because of which none of my ways were getting worked to save the data. After I removed the unique key I was able to Store them in the data. However for Campaign_id=0 it gave me only status=True but I wanted it to be false. and when I added the extra lines(in the edit) it gave me 4 records.